# Creating random XML entries in Java or Perl

Tags: java, xml, perl

I am looking for a method to insert random XML data in Java (or Perl).

```
<vehicles ID="DJ3RKFF9">
    <vehicle>
        <make>Toyota</make>
        <model>Yaris</model>
        <year>2009</year>
    </vehicle>
    <vehicle>
        <make>Ford</make>
        <model>Taurus</model>
        <year>2008</year>
    </vehicle>
</vehicles>
```

In the above example, I would need to make the `ID` attribute a random series of characters. The rest of the data can remain the same.

It is only the insertion that I need help with, not creating the strings (thanks Sinan Ünür!)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to narrow this down. Are you having problems generating random data, or inserting it into the XML ?

Comment: Sorry, the second one. I've figured out how to create the random string, I just can't figure out how to insert them.

Comment: DOM implementations generate an id attribute if you don't specify one so that each node has a unique id, maybe you could use that/rename your ID attribute to id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, basically, your question is *how can I generate an eight character random string consisting of digits and capital letters?*:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

my $tmpl = <<EO_XML;
<vehicles ID="%s">
    <vehicle>
        <make>Toyota</make>
        <model>Yaris</model>
        <year>2009</year>
    </vehicle>
    <vehicle>
        <make>Ford</make>
        <model>Taurus</model>
        <year>2008</year>
    </vehicle>
</vehicles>
EO_XML

my $generator = make_id_generator('A' .. 'Z', 0 .. 9);

printf $tmpl, $generator->() for 1 .. 10;

sub make_id_generator {
    my @chars = @_;
    return sub {
        join '', @chars[ map { rand @chars } 1 .. 8 ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Although I had figured that out, I like yours a lot better than the one I pieced together. I'll clarify the question to illustrate that it's just the inserting that I need help with.

Comment: @ryantmer I saw your comments after I posted my answer. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Although there's nothing *wrong* with the templating solution, I want to show that it's not necessarily *hard* to do it in a "proper" XML-slinging kind of way, and it might save you a lot of time later on if your requirements ever change.

That said, here's a sketch of how you might build this up with XML::Twig. Any corners that I've cut are strictly in the name of producing a nice example snippet that fits on one screen :)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

sub gen_id {
  my @chars = ('A'..'Z', '0'..'9');
  join '', @chars[ map { rand @chars } 1 .. 8 ];
}

sub gen_vehicle {
  my $vehicle = XML::Twig::Elt->new('vehicle');
  while (my ($key, $value) = splice @_, 0, 2) {
    XML::Twig::Elt->new($key => $value)
        ->paste(last_child => $vehicle);
  }
  $vehicle;
}

sub gen_vehicles {
  my $vehicles = XML::Twig::Elt->new('vehicles');
  $vehicles->set_att( ID => gen_id() );

  gen_vehicle(make => 'Toyota', model => 'Yaris', year => 2009)
    ->paste(last_child => $vehicles);
  gen_vehicle(make => 'Ford', model => 'Taurus', year => 2008)
    ->paste(last_child => $vehicles);

  $vehicles;
}

XML::Twig->set_pretty_print('indented');
gen_vehicles()->print;
```

Answer (score 1):

Much as it pains me to solve XML problem using regular expressions, in this case we can probably make an exception:

```
$ perl -ipe '{my $string = generate_random_string(); s/<vehicles ID="DJ3RKFF9">/<vehicles ID="$string">/;}' myfile.xml
```

a random string generator can be found by googling "perl random string", for example this:
http://guymal.com/mycode/generate_random_string/

Answer (score 1):

To do this in Java you can use DOM: This will add the attribute value to an xml file (xmlInput) which doesn't have the ID attribute set

```
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFac = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = dbFac.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse("resources/xmlinput.xml");

        NodeList vehicles = doc.getElementsByTagName("vehicles");
        NamedNodeMap attributes = vehicles.item(0).getAttributes();
        Node ID = attributes.getNamedItem("ID");
        String randomString = createRandomString();
        ID.setNodeValue(randomString);

        XMLSerializer serializer = new XMLSerializer();
         serializer.setOutputCharStream(
                 new java.io.FileWriter("resources/xmloutput.xml")
                 );  
      serializer.serialize(doc);
```

I left out the implementation for createRandomString() but that part should be easy

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure what the specs are for this project, so I've done it in Perl for now. However, if it needs to be done in Java, this will be useful! :)